# Move files from folders into a new one

Tags: bash

Hy,

I'm facing a problem with this matter, I want to write a bash command, let me clarify this problem:

I have some dirs with pics within:

```
|-Dir1
|--pic2.jpg
|--pic3.jpg
|--pic4.jpg
|--pic5.jpg
|--n...

|-Dir2
|--pic2.jpg
|--pic3.jpg
|--pic4.jpg
|--pic5.jpg
|--n...

|-Dir3
|--pic2.jpg
|--pic3.jpg
|--pic4.jpg
|--pic5.jpg
|--n...
```

All I want to do is move just 3 pics from each folder to a new one. It doesn't matter if it's random pictures or whatever.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried with the command "find" but I can't solve the problem to stop at the number 3 picture, something like this:

#!/bin/bash
find Dir1 -type f -name '*.jpg' | while read -r FILE; do
    DIRNAME=${FILE%/*}
    mkdir -p "../ALL" && mv "$FILE" "../ALL/"
done

Comment: Do you want to move the [random] pics into just one destination directory?

Comment: That's right. Donovan.

Comment: Try splicing a | head -n 3 in after your find command. That will only spit out the first three lines to the while part of the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

start with this... which will move 3 files into another directory

**move3.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 2 ] ; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <SOURCE_DIR> <DEST_DIR>"
  exit 1
fi
if [ ! -d "$1" ] ; then
  echo "$1 is not a directory, please supply a source directory"
  exit 1
fi
if [ ! -d "$2" ] ; then
  echo "$2 is not a directory, please supply a destination directory"
  exit 1
fi
FILES=$(ls "$1" | tail -3)
for FILE in $FILES ; do
  mv "$1"/$FILE "$2"
done
```

You can then build upon that to send any combination of source/destination directories to be moved.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't works with folder names with spaces, some workaround to solve this?

Comment: Well, honestly, this was meant to get you started in the right direction.  If you enclose your folder names in quotes, it should work... `move3.sh "directory with space" "destination with space"`